# fancyhdr: color of page number not changing in document, even though it changes in other documents

Tags: fancyhdr

For this problem, I am using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{concmath}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\definecolor{blueish}{rgb}{0.565,0.886,1}  % blue-ish
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.15}  % very dark gray

% ==================================================
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{scifi}{%
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textcolor{blueish}{\thepage}}% Page # in middle/centre of footer
}
\makeatother
% ==================================================

\pagestyle{scifi}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{darkgray}
\color{blueish}

\title{A test sci-fi document}

\date{2958.16.32}

\maketitle
\reversemarginpar

% -----------------------------------------
\begin{enumerate}
    \item How many errors can each of the following codes detect/correct? (assuming NND decoder)
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $\mathcal{C} = \{000000, 111111, 000111\}, q = 2$

            Computing the minimum distance between any two code words:
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
                            & $000000$ & $111111$ & $000111$ \\
                        \hline
                        $000000$ & $0$ & &  \\
                        \hline
                        $111111$ & $6$ & $0$ & \\
                        \hline
                        $000111$ & $3$ & $3$ & $0$ \\
                    \end{tabular}
                \end{center}

            Since the minimum distance between code words is $3$:
                \begin{align*}
                    &u \leq d - 1 \\
                    &u \leq 3 - 1 \\
                    &u \leq 2 \\
                    & \\
                    &v \leq \lfloor\frac{d - 1}{2}\rfloor \\
                    &v \leq \lfloor\frac{3 - 1}{2}\rfloor \\
                    &v \leq 1
                \end{align*}

            So, this code can correct $1$ or less errors, and can detect $2$ or less errors.

        \end{enumerate}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

It produces output like (click to zoom in):

[image]

It is difficult to see, but the page number comes out in black at the bottom of the page.

Surprisingly, in another example where I had much simpler text, the page number comes out as wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
% code hijacked from: https://gist.github.com/fgrosse/5807324
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{concmath}

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\definecolor{blueish}{rgb}{0.565,0.886,1}  % blue-ish
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.15,0.15,0.15}  % very dark gray

% ==================================================
\makeatletter
\fancypagestyle{scifi}{%
    \fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
    \fancyfoot[C]{\textcolor{blueish}{\thepage}}% Page # in middle/centre of footer
}
\makeatother
% ==================================================

\pagestyle{scifi}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{darkgray}
\color{blueish}

Hello world.

\end{document}
```

Output (click to zoom in):

[image]

Also, for some reason, a black bar is produced above "Hello World."

Why is `fancyhdr` behaving this way?

Comment: If you're using a similar style to `plain` (nothing but a centred `\thepage` in the footer), then you can just use `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` and not have to set *any* `\pagestyle` in your document. That is, you effectively redefine `plain`, and `plain` is the default.

Comment: @Werner Sadly, I have plans to do some more with `fancyhdr` (namely, put in TikZ generated art in headers/footers), so I should probably stick with the more flexible approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really related directly to fancyhdr this is just the usual issue that `\maketitle`  (and `\chapter` etc) issue `\thispagestyle{plain}` so you need to use `fancyhdr` package to redefine plain page style or simply do

```
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{scifi}
```

Comment: You're a genius. Mind if I shoe in another question? What's up with that black bar above "Hello World"?

Comment: @user89 that's just the default ruled header from fancyhdr , comment out your `\pagecolor` and you'll see it more clearly. you can set the rule width to 0pt see fancyhder doc

Comment: Thanks a million! That's enough for me to figure it out :)